# List Numbering style CSS, Right Numbering like Arabic Numbering system

Tags: html, css

I need to make an ordered list with the numbers being to the right. something like this:

[image]

and so on.

And not in the normal way:

1. Item
2. Item
3. Item

How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: I think there's no duplication here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)**.

**`.List.A`** is `text-align`ed `left` with the pseudo-class `::before` and no content ("Item" is in `::before`.)

**`.List.B`** is `text-align`ed `right` with the pseudo-class `::after` and no content ("Item" is in `::after`.)

**`.List.C`** is `text-align`ed `right` with the pseudo-class `::after` and has content ("item" is in `<li>`.) ⭐

---

### Demo

---

```css
ol {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid blue
}

.list {
  counter-reset: number;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* The "\a0" is a space */

.list.A li::before {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: "Item\a0\a0."counter(number)"\a0";
}

.list.B li,
.list.C li {
  text-align: right;
}

.list.B li::after {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: "Item\a0\a0."counter(number)"\a0";
}

.list.C li::after {
  counter-increment: number;
  content: "\a0\a0."counter(number)"\a0";
}
```

```html
<ol class='list A'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>

<ol class='list B'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>

<ol class='list C'>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

---

⭐ As per Temani Afif comment

Comment: better keep the content inside Li as it may not be the same and use after instead of before

Comment: @TemaniAfif Duly noted, sir, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply  `direction: rtl;` on the ol tag and it will make the numbers go from the right.

for example:

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rtl">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```